# How would I extend this Excel 2019 formula for every other row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

what formula would I use if i wanted to extend this out to D543?

```
=AVERAGE(D7,D9,D11,D13,D17,D19,D21,D23,D25,D27,D31,D33,D35)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array formula to do this, which will allow you to easily change your range.

Use the below:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISODD(ROW(D7:D45)),D7:D45,""))
```

To make it an array formula, enter it pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter all together

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2019, you probably have the `SEQUENCE` function.  So try:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($D:$D,SEQUENCE((543-7)/2+1,,7,2)))
```